# Backbone: fetch the data from a json file which is in the client part

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Using `Backbone.js`, I would like to fetch the data from a Json file in the client part when calling the fetch method on model or collection instance.

The `url property` in my collection (`MyCol`) point to the following json file which looks like this:

```
[
  {title: "_My trip to Bali", src: "bali-trip.jpg"},
  {title: "_The flight home", src: "long-flight-oofta.jpg"},
  {title: "_Uploading pix", src: "too-many-pics.jpg"}
]
```

I perform the following commands:

```
myCol = new MyCol();
myCol.fetch(); // the Request Method GET is ok 
myCol.toJSON(); // []
```

Comment: We need more information: 1) Which is the URL of your JSON file? 2) Which is the URL of the Backbone request? 3) What is the _Network_ console showing you? 4) What is something like this `myCol.fetch({ success: function(){ console.log("SUCCESS"); }, error: function(){ console.log("ERROR"); }` showing you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fguillen is right saying you can debug your code simply using `success and error callbacks`.
Anyway the error is in your json format because of the members which need to be a string.

Try this and it will work:

```
[
  {"title": "_My trip to Bali", "src": "bali-trip.jpg"},
  {"title": "_The flight home", "src": "long-flight-oofta.jpg"},
  {"title": "_Uploading pix", "src": "too-many-pics.jpg"}
]
```

Answer (score 4):

Remember that fetch is not a synchronous function. The fetch method will initiate a request to the server and you are alerted to the response through an event or callback.

Take a look at the backbone documentation for the fetch method http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch.

Try doing something like this instead.

```
myCol = new MyCol();
myCol.fetch({
    success: function() { //This is fired if the request is succesful
        myCol.toJSON();
    }
});
```

Or

```
myCol = new MyCol();
myCol.on('change', function() { //This is fired if the model's attributes change
   myCol.toJSON();
});
myCol.fetch();
```

Or as @roberkules mentioned, fetch returns a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR), so you could do this.

```
myCol = new MyCol();
myCol.fetch()
     .done(function() {
         myCol.toJSON();
      })
      .fail(function() {
          alert('Oh No!');
      });
```

Comment: I prefer `myCol.fetch().done(function(){ myCol.toJSON(); });`